# Implementing auth with Vue.js on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have an error in my Vue.js component

Code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Movie;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\CommentSpam;
use App\Models\CommentVote;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

```
if(Auth::user()){
   $voteByUser = CommentVote::where('comment_id',$key->id)->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
   $spamComment = CommentSpam::where('comment_id',$key->id)->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

Kernel :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin.level' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminLevel::class,
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    'basic.level' => \App\Http\Middleware\BasicLevel::class,
    'creator.level' => \App\Http\Middleware\CreatorLevel::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'editor.level' => \App\Http\Middleware\EditorLevel::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

In the end the problem, It doesn't recognize the middlwere auth.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using vue as an SPA, the you need to intergrate sanctum
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum